# reactive cocoa Avoid observing on flags to perform side effect

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to understand how to avoid use of flags to perform side-effects after an operation. In my code, I open a network connection after which, I setup code to perform a heart-beat with the server regularly. When a request is sent on this connection, I need to reset the heart beat timer , this is how my code looks -

```
 (RACSignal *) connect: (NSString *) server {
     return [[MIConnection connect: server ] 
             doComplete {
              [self setupHeartBeat];

            }];
     }

  -(void) setupHeartBeat {
      [[[[[RACObserve (self, heartBeatReset) ignore@(NO)]

       map:^RACStream *(id value) {
           return [RACSignal interval:7
                        onScheduler:scheduler withLeeway:5]
                startWith:[NSDate date]]
        }]
        switchToLatest]
        flattenMap:^RACStream *(MIConnection * theConnection) {
           return [self sendHeartBeat] ;
       }]

        subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        self.heartBeatReset = NO;

         NSLog(@"Done with sending heartbeat");
     }];

    -(RACSignal *) sendRequest: (id) request {

     return [[MIConnection sendRequest: request ] 
             doComplete {
              self.heartBeatReset = YES;
            }];
     }
```

As you can see, I am using a flag "heartBeatReset", to reset the timer for a heartbeat to be sent. What will be a better way to achieve the above? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag property could be replaced with an empty method. The implementation of `-setupHeartBeat` could then use `-rac_signalForSelector:` on the empty method, instead of `RACObserve` on the flag. Calling the empty method would be semantically the same as assigning `YES` to the flag.

```
- (void)resetHeartBeat {
}

- (RACSignal *)sendRequest:(id)request {
    return [[MIConnection sendRequest:request]
        doComplete {
            [self resetHeartBeat];
        }];
}

- (void)setupHeartBeat {
    RACSignal *heartBeatTimer = [[RACSignal
        interval:7 onScheduler:scheduler withLeeway:5]
        startWithDate:[NSDate date]];

    [[[[[self
        rac_signalForSelector:@selector(resetHeartBeat)]
        mapReplace:heartBeatTimer]
        switchToLatest]
        flattenMap:^(id _) {
            return [self sendHeartBeat];
        }]
        subscribe:nil];
}
```